# Type hinting for generic factory method

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm curious whether it is possible to infer a generic type (for type hinting) through a type argument in Python.

For example, consider a (fairly stupid) factory method:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')

class Test1(object):
    def test1(self):
        pass

class Test2(object):
    def test2(self):
        pass

# Is the type hinting correct here?
def create( t: Type[T] ) -> T:
    if t == Test1:
        return Test1()
    elif t == Test2:
        return Test2()
    else:
        raise ValueError()

instance1 = create( Test1 )
instance2 = create( Test2 )
```

Neither Visual Studio 2017 nor intellij ultimate 2018 seem to be picking up the correct types of instance1 and instance2 here, at least not in terms of intellisense.
I'm curious though if my usage is wrong, or if this just isn't supported by the IDEs yet.

Thanks

Comment: Can you present a more concrete case of the factory function? Do the classes that your factory function accept have some relation? A Base class may help you here and I think it may simplify the type hints also providing further information.

Comment: Offtopic: python 3 does not require to inherit from `object`

Comment: I do not have much experience with type hinting, but your example seems to much almost exactly (logic-wise) with example in the doc string of `typing.Type` ... so my best guess its IDE's "fault"

Comment: @Drecker I think you are right - I've just tried with IntelliJ 2019 and it works fine there

Answer (score 2):

Your type signature is perfectly fine, and your IDEs should be reporting that `instance` and `instance2` are of types `Test1` and `Test2` respectively. This is in fact the output you'll get if you try running your code against [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). (To reveal what mypy thinks what your types are, try temporarily adding the `reveal_locals()` pseudofunction to the bottom of your code before running mypy.)

---

However, the actual *body* of your code is actually technically unsound as well! The caller of your code could pass in a custom object that decides to always consider itself equal to everything. For example:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

class ForceAlwaysEqual(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        return True

class Hijacked(metaclass=ForceAlwaysEqual): pass

class Test1: pass

class Test2: pass

T = TypeVar('T')

def create(t: Type[T]) -> T:
    if t == Test1:
        return Test1()
    elif t == Test2:
        return Test2()
    else:
        raise ValueError()


mystery = create(Hijacked)
print(type(mystery))
```

If you try running this code in Python, we'll print out `Test1` at the very end: the call to `create` won't throw a ValueError!

What's basically happening here is that I added a custom metaclass to `Hijacked` so that doing `Hijacked == blah` will always return True. This causes the first check inside create (`t == Test1`) to happen to be true, so we return Test1, violating the signature of your function.

So if your IDE is also not indicating any issues with the *body* of your `create` function, that would actually be technically yet another bug on their part.

(The more general lesson here is that in Python, it's unfortunately very difficult for type checkers to infer much of anything from equality checks since they could at any moment be redefined to do any amount of arbitrary bullshit.)