# Python type hinting for generic factory function

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to come up with a set of Python (3.10, FWIW) type hints, that will make mypy happy about a generic factory function I've written:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar

@dataclass
class _Base:
    ...


@dataclass
class A(_Base):
    foo: str


@dataclass
class B(_Base):
    bar: str


T = TypeVar("T", bound=_Base)


def make_instance(value: str, cls: type[T]) -> T:
    reveal_locals()
    if cls is A:
        return A(foo=value)
    if cls is B:
        return B(bar=value)
    raise NotImplementedError(f"No impl for type {cls.__name__}")


a = make_instance("A", A)
b = make_instance("B", B)

reveal_locals()
```

Running mypy (v0.990) on this example leads to the following output:

```
scratch.py:23: note: Revealed local types are:
scratch.py:23: note:     cls: Type[T`-1]
scratch.py:23: note:     value: builtins.str
scratch.py:25: error: Incompatible return value type (got "A", expected "T")  [return-value]
            return A(foo=value)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
scratch.py:27: error: Incompatible return value type (got "B", expected "T")  [return-value]
            return B(bar=value)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
scratch.py:34: note: Revealed local types are:
scratch.py:34: note:     a: scratch.A
scratch.py:34: note:     b: scratch.B
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The type of `a` and `b` is correctly inferred, however the return statements seem to upset mypy. Is there any way to express the fact that `make_instance` returns an instance of the type `cls`, which it receives as a parameter? I can always put a `# type: ignore` on them, but I'd like to understand the underlying cause for the error, if possible.

I already found this related question, but the solution doesn't seem to apply in my case, since there mypy seemed happy enough to accept the type hints: [Type hinting for generic factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705255/type-hinting-for-generic-factory-method)

Comment: perhaps this is good for the mypy issue board, it seems to me this should work

Comment: `cast` or `# type: ignore`. It's an old `mypy` problem, it almost always fails to infer that something is of type `A` and still matched typevar `_T`, even if it is quite obvious (I'd replace `A` and `B` with `cls` in instantiation for semantic reasons, but it doesn't help `mypy`).

Comment: @SUTerliakov - `cast(T, A(...))` works, thanks!